# Logging data to SD card from software serial

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, adafruit

I have an Arduino Uno and an Adafruit data logging shield and I have connected a digital pressure sensor that uses serial communication. The sensor requires a character to start transmitting data. I have managed to read the data using this code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8,9); 

int depth;

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);
    mySerial.begin(9600);
    mySerial.print("C");

}

void loop() 
{

 if (mySerial.available()) {

   depth = mySerial.read();

 }

}
```

This returns the following:

> C1000
>   C1000
>   C1000

where 1000 is the value.

I have written another code that logs data to the shield and tested with other sensors but I cannot log data from this sensor by modifying the above code and cannot find any relevant examples.
If I add something like this it does not return the same value.

```
logfile.println(depth);
```

Complete newbie in so any suggestions are welcome.

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95775/discussion-on-question-by-nik-ol-logging-data-to-sd-card-from-software-serial).

Answer (score 1):

use the C as the line start indicator. if received char is 'C' then do a `file.println();` example with output to Serial

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8,9); 

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    mySerial.begin(9600);
    mySerial.print("C");
}

void loop() {
 if (mySerial.available()) {
   char c = mySerial.read();
   if (c == 'C') {
     Serial.println();
   }
   Serial.write(c);
 }
}
```

Comment: But this code does not do anything different than the simple code. My problem is not that I am not reading the data or that I do not see the data printed in the serial monitor. I do receive all the data. The problem comes when I try to log the data. I think the data come in so fast from the serial, but when I add delays everything is messed up.

Comment: it prints completely different then the code in Question. did you try it?

Comment: Yes I tried it. It prints the same with a gap between its measurement. Also it uses a lot more of the dynamic variable. But it prints the same with a gap between each C1000

Comment: is it not what you want? every set on a new line?

Comment: No. I want to log the data to an SD card. When I use this code to log I get one number every second. I have added a screen shot in the original post. I want to get all the 4 numbers in one second and then the new 4 numbers in the next second.

Comment: you stil have println instead or write or you look at lines recorded before the change

Comment: I have completely removed the serial.println () after the if but it does not change anything

Comment: in my Answer you have a complete sketch. run it as it is. don't change anything

Comment: I have run it as it is. The update I have added in the original post is when I run this sketch. It still prints its byte in a different line. 6171 is one reading and the code returns it in 4 seconds and its number in a different line

Comment: do you have 9600 baud set in Serial Monitor?

Comment: does the device send data at 9600 baud?

Comment: yes to both questions. When I use the sketch I posted initially (at 9600) it returns the data in one line as expected continuously. I get this problem when I add any type of delay. For example when I log every 1 s, I get the problem I mentioned.

Comment: you can't add a delay. the device doesn't stop to send data, the serial buffer overflows and some part of he data will be lost

Comment: So how can I log this data? There is no way?

Comment: you could after the delay first read the buffer clean (read SERIAL_RX_BUFFER_SIZE count of bytes), the wait for C and read until next C